# Melted Electrical Tape Toxic?

Tags: soldering

I'm not very experienced with electrical soldering, but I decided to give it a go. I don't have any kind of clamp to hold the protoboard in place, so I used electrical tape to hold it down to the table. While I was soldering, I noticed a whiff of nasty stench, and when I turned the board over, I realized I had melted a hole right through a strip of electrical tape.

I was outside, so I guess you could say the area was well-ventilated, but I'm still worried. Could this have caused any lasting effects on my health? What are the risks of electrical tape fumes?

Thanks, any input appreciated.

Comment: I'm still alive... it's never had any notishable eflects on meeble.

Comment: Yes, this stuff is very dangerous.  It causes death in about 80-100 years, less for older people.

Comment: @Mindstormscreator [here](http://www.amazon.com/SE-MZ101B-Helping-Hand-Magnifier/dp/B000RB38X8/ref=sr_1_1/188-8154946-0860625?ie=UTF8&qid=1420230517&sr=8-1&keywords=helping%20hand%20soldering) is a link to a tool called "helping hands" which will hold the board for you while you solder. It's cheap and very helpful.

Comment: Thank you, but believe it or not, I just ordered one, along with some much-needed desoldering supplies, from Amazon. They'll arrive tomorrow. Yes, I was that impatient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the (PVC) tape by itself isn't according to its material safety data sheet, (see http://www.lhdottie.com/pdf/msds/360_%28PVCTape%29.pdf) but because of the high chlorine content it does tend to give off pretty nasty smelling vapours (HCl) which can be irritating.

In large amounts burning PVC could produce dioxins but for a small piece of tape I wouldn't consider that a real problem.

Comment: I would be more concerned with the Hydrogen Cyanide being given off with burning PVC

Comment: @JonRB as the PVC is made up from C(2)H(3)Cl polymer (no nitrogen) and we are talking fairly low temperature (charring) type burning I can't see how it would actually produce an HCN molecule.

Comment: There is the adhesive as well. While the PVC will primarily give off Co,CO2,HCL, its not the only material in Electrical tape. That aside: http://www.vec.gr.jp/english/library/fire/2.html

Comment: @JonRB Water, if breathed in sufficient concentration and over a significant amount of time, is lethal. There is no real world comparison between a little bit of charred PVC tape in an open environment and an enclosed fire where significant amounts of PVC are consumed at high temperatures.I feel that I have given a realistic answer to the question asked but please feel free to post your own answer the question rather than continue this discussion in comments.